# Is “nous n'en sommes pas encore à” an expression?

Tags: expressions, pronoms, prépositions

I was reading an article of a new wireless technology and came across this sentence:

> nous n’en sommes pas encore à évoquer une quelconque date de lancement
>   de la LTE Advanced dans l’hexagone.

I cannot work out what the "en" is for here. Could it be that it's part of some idiomatic expression?

Comment: Yes it's an idiom. Here "*En être à quelque chose*" is elliptical for ["*en être arriver à*"](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/7082/358). Not to be confused with ["*En être*"](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_%C3%AAtre).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"En" can be either a pronoun (to replace a nominal group starting with de/du/de la/des) or a preposition (related to place/manner/matter/material).
Here I actually have trouble seeing which one it is (although I'm French :-O).

Anyway, I think it's idiomatic : en arriver à (quelque chose), en être (quelque part).
Also it's mostly (average ?) spoken language, I wouldn't expect that in text.

Litterally it stands for "arriver/être {au point où}/{au moment de}/{prêt à} ..."

In your context : "nous ne sommes pas encore prêts à évoquer ... "

Answer (score 1):

*En* is a complicated word. In this form, it is a pronoun with no antecedent, which is a bit of a strange concept (I think some grammars classify it as a particle, i.e. a word that doesn't fall into any neat classification). This happens in a number of idioms.

*En être à* means “to have reached the stage when”.

> Nous n’en sommes pas encore à évoquer une quelconque date de lancement de la LTE Advanced dans l’hexagone.
> *We have not reached the point where we might discuss a launch date for LTE Advanced in France.*
>
> Où en êtes-vous ? — J'en ai fait la moitié.
> How far have you got? — I've processed half of them.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the " **en** " refers to the `matter/situation/subject of discussion` the news article is discussing about. In this situation I think it's about the

> **en** = date de lancement de la LTE Advanced dans l’hexagone

But also it's a common expression assiociated to the alternative of saying

> nous n'en parlons pas encore = nous n’en sommes pas encore à évoquer